# complain .so(sharedlibraries) file not found in android runtime

Tags: android, shared-libraries

in android runtime the app crashed for it complain that a .so file is not found:

```
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.tencent.tmgp.com.mmgame.mybrick/app_dex/ysdk_hackdex.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.tencent.tmgp.com.mmgame.mybrick-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tencent.tmgp.com.mmgame.mybrick-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libYSDK.so"
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.tencent.ysdk.framework.hotfix.impl.c.k(Unknown Source)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.tencent.ysdk.framework.hotfix.impl.c.a(Unknown Source)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.tencent.ysdk.framework.hotfix.impl.b.a(Unknown Source)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.tencent.ysdk.api.YSDKApi.onCreate(Unknown Source)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.tencent.tmgp.com.mmgame.mybrick.MyMainActivity.onCreate(MyMainActivity.java:42)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6074)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:167)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
08-10 12:52:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(26753):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

But the `.so` file it complains missing was in the apk file when I checked the 
unzipped `lib/armeabi` folder :

[image]

This only happen on some phone model to be noticed.

What has went wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: sorry bro，didn’t recall a solution for this